# Protect only certain routes with koa-jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt, koa

I cannot figure it out how to protect only some routes with koa-jwt.

I don't want to do this because I will never get 404 errors:

```
    this.app.use(unprotectedRoutes.routes())
    this.app.use(jwt({ secret: 'my secret key' }))
    this.app.use(protectedRoutes.routes())
```

The routes that doesn't exist in **unprotectedRoutes** will pass throw jwt and I'll get a Authenticated error.

What I want to do is that jwt only applies on **protectedRoutes**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the `protectedRoutes` is a router instance you should be able to add the jwt only to that specific router using `protectedRoutes.use(jwt({ secret: 'my secret key' }))`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Molda! I did that but in a wrong place. Now I figure it out where I had to put it. It was so late last night. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

I had to put it on the file where I declared protectedRoutes

protectedRoutes.use(jwt({ secret: 'my secret key' }))

Thanks and sorry if it was so obvious.